# How to make a fixed Tabbar from react-bootstrap package Reactjs with Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

Im trying to make my Tabbar fixed position...

The package im using is react-bootstrap:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/

And This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs, Tab } from 'react-bootstrap';

const datacenter = () => {
  return (
    <div className="content-area">
      <Tabs defaultActiveKey="Dashboard" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
        <Tab eventKey="Dashboard" title="Dashboard" className="fullheightfixed">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus amet
            eum, optio non omnis voluptate quibusdam sunt ex nulla est commodi
            unde obcaecati, corrupti maiores ab culpa quas ipsam excepturi? A
            asperiores maxime ipsam soluta inventore, velit consequatur iure
            earum adipisci odio vel sit quisquam, voluptatum, quam mollitia
            ratione. Nemo porro commodi repellat sint aperiam laudantium
            sapiente doloribus, tempora reiciendis reprehenderit! Atque
            recusandae velit dolore. Praesentium, doloremque libero consectetur
            soluta ad quas in quisquam facilis sed ipsam! Molestiae tempora
            reprehenderit odit deleniti? Odio quae eveniet tempora repudiandae.
            Repudiandae recusandae veritatis incidunt, dolorem dolorum molestias
            modi cum exercitationem nihil illo ab.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus amet
            eum, optio non omnis voluptate quibusdam sunt ex nulla est commodi
            unde obcaecati, corrupti maiores ab culpa quas ipsam excepturi? A
            asperiores maxime ipsam soluta inventore, velit consequatur iure
            earum adipisci odio vel sit quisquam, voluptatum, quam mollitia
            ratione. Nemo porro commodi repellat sint aperiam laudantium
            sapiente doloribus, tempora reiciendis reprehenderit! Atque
            recusandae velit dolore. Praesentium, doloremque libero consectetur
            soluta ad quas in quisquam facilis sed ipsam! Molestiae tempora
            reprehenderit odit deleniti? Odio quae eveniet tempora repudiandae.
            Repudiandae recusandae veritatis incidunt, dolorem dolorum molestias
            modi cum exercitationem nihil illo ab.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus amet
            eum, optio non omnis voluptate quibusdam sunt ex nulla est commodi
            unde obcaecati, corrupti maiores ab culpa quas ipsam excepturi? A
            asperiores maxime ipsam soluta inventore, velit consequatur iure
            earum adipisci odio vel sit quisquam, voluptatum, quam mollitia
            ratione. Nemo porro commodi repellat sint aperiam laudantium
            sapiente doloribus, tempora reiciendis reprehenderit! Atque
            recusandae velit dolore. Praesentium, doloremque libero consectetur
            soluta ad quas in quisquam facilis sed ipsam! Molestiae tempora
            reprehenderit odit deleniti? Odio quae eveniet tempora repudiandae.
            Repudiandae recusandae veritatis incidunt, dolorem dolorum molestias
            modi cum exercitationem nihil illo ab.
          </p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus amet
            eum, optio non omnis voluptate quibusdam sunt ex nulla est commodi
            unde obcaecati, corrupti maiores ab culpa quas ipsam excepturi? A
            asperiores maxime ipsam soluta inventore, velit consequatur iure
            earum adipisci odio vel sit quisquam, voluptatum, quam mollitia
            ratione. Nemo porro commodi repellat sint aperiam laudantium
            sapiente doloribus, tempora reiciendis reprehenderit! Atque
            recusandae velit dolore. Praesentium, doloremque libero consectetur
            soluta ad quas in quisquam facilis sed ipsam! Molestiae tempora
            reprehenderit odit deleniti? Odio quae eveniet tempora repudiandae.
            Repudiandae recusandae veritatis incidunt, dolorem dolorum molestias
            modi cum exercitationem nihil illo ab.
          </p>
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  );
};

export default datacenter;
```

This is my code in codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-sound-ufkig?file=/src/App.js:353-359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fullheightfixed` class can simply take the following properties :-

```css
.fullheightfixed {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
```

`overflow:auto` to make the content inside `Tab` scroll when sufficient space isn't available. And that space can be calculated by subtracting **tab navbar** height from **100vh** which is 100 % of available viewport height.

Here is a working sandbox :-

[image: Edit Fixed height Tab]

Comment: it did worked but i have a bit of a problem, can you help me?

Comment: so, im having two scrolls on my screen right now and i just want to have 1 scrollbar not double, can you pls help? btw i upvote since you help me, thanks. it will be better if you could help me on the scroll problem, thanks again!